# Adding display data to model for controller ember.js

Tags: model, ember.js, controller

From my understanding controllers are used to decorate the data or add any data that does not belong to the model (sever).  However, I'm trying to understand how to add display data to the model data so that I can pass to the template in ember.js

Below is an example of the code.  There might be a better way to do this, but so maybe I'm making it more difficult then it needs to be.

When the user clicks on the div, I want a new css 'select' class be appended so it lights up the div.

Actions

1. user clicks on div
2. userSelect action is triggered and in the controller isSelected is set to be true.  This will update the template and append the
   'selected' tag to the class attribute resulting the div to be
   updated.

Issues:

1. I want to add a display attribute isSelected for each user in the model and not just to the model like i'm doing now.  Is that possible?
2. Currently, with the way its implemented the 'selected' tag gets displayed only when isSelected = false.  Either the logic is reversed or the order in which the isSelected is being binde to the new value occurs after the rendering of the template.

user.js

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName:     DS.attr('string'),
    lastName:      DS.attr('string')
});

App.User.FIXTURES = 
[
 {
   id:          1,
   firstName:   'Derek',
   lastName:    "H",

 },
 {
   id:          2,
   firstName:   'Test',
   lastName:    "H",

 }
]
```

UserListController.js

```
App.UserListController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    isSelected: false,
    userSelect: function(userId){

        this.set('isSelected', true);

        console.debug(userId + " isSelected:" + this.get('isSelected'));
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="userList" data-template-name="userList">
   {{#each controller}}  
        <div {{bindAttr class="isSelected:selected:notselected"}} {{action userSelect id}}>
         </div>
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

I realize that I could just manipulate the DOM and append the class, but I wanted to know the right approach in which you would do it for ember specifically.

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's alright to add property to your model.

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),

    isSelected: false
});
```

Your route should be like this:

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() { return App.User.find(); }
});
```

So, I modified your template:

```
 {{#each model}}  
    <div {{bindAttr class="isSelected:selected:notselected"}} 
         {{action 'userSelect' this}}>
    </div>
 {{/each}}
```

And the controller:

```
App.UserController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    userSelect: function(user){
       user.set('isSelected', true);
    }
});
```

It should work fine.

Comment: This isn't the route i wanted to go since isSelected isn't really server data, but more display data.  Thanks thou!

Comment: It is not a server data. If you want to specify an attribute as server data, you set DS.attr('string') or Ember.attr('string'). It is designed like that to differentiate between server and display data.

Comment: This approach can work but is not recommended, an isSelected property really belongs on controller not the model. Understanding why is subtle but important - while there is a single model object for each user there may be many controllers. That user object may appear in a few lists, in search results, on an edit page, etc. If you put application state properties like isSelected on model they will bleed thru and lead to really hard-to-debug problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `isSelected` property is on `App.UserListController`, which represents the list not each individual user. You've got the right idea - use controllers to decorate model objects - but to make this work you need a controller instance for each user. That is what the [{{each}} helper's itemController property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each) is for.

Check out this blog post for a great explanation:

http://gaslight.co/blog/intermediate-ember-controller-concepts

Comment: I actually attempted this way, however I was getting issues with applying it to a controller that is only associated with a model. I'll post the example in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem well.

We can set properties to individual objects in array controller.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="userList" data-template-name="userList">
   {{#each controller}} 
       {{#if selected}}
           div {{bindAttr class="selected"}}></div>
       {{else}}
        <div {{bindAttr class="notselected"}} {{action userSelect this}}>
         </div>
      {{/if}}
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

**action userSelect**

```
App.UserListController=Em.ArrayController.extend({
  userSelect:function(ob){
    this.map(function(o,i){
      Em.set(o,"selected",false);
      if(ob.id===o.id)
        Em.set(ob,"selected",true);
    });
  }
});
```

Check out this [Bin](http://jsbin.com/eToQEDu/2).
Check out this [Bin](http://jsbin.com/ocilOLo/5#/threads) also